# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

All I want to do is start a new intent on click of a button. Here is my code(I have removed irrelevant parts):

`activity_login.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.android.altro.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_up_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:onClick="registerNewUser"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_up"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

On clicking `@+id/email_sign_up_button` `registerNewUser` is called. I have defined this fuction in `LoginActivity.java`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

       /* Button mRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_up_button);
        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
    }

    public void registerNewUser(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I also tried doing it by finding view and then creating an intent (the code is commented out in `onCreate()` method. That also gave me the same error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.altro/com.example.android.altro.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: trim down your code and be more specific with where you think the problem is.  it will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: post your register activity

Answer (score 0):

You have only one `Button` with id `email_sign_up_button`
Please check your `layout`. Also try replacing

```
Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
```

With

```
Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_up_button);
```

Comment: Thats not a problem, I have removed that button code to make it short. Its there.